# How can JMeter identify what to optimize in a website?

Tags: testing, jmeter, automated-tests, performance-testing, load-testing

I'm new with website performance testing field and will be using JMeter. After playing with it, I am still having troubles with identifying what to optimize in a website load time?

I'm currently still learning about the load testing - who should I give the performance report to? Developers/Programmers? or Network department? Example of an error I usually get is 502 error or timeouts.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter cannot identify anything, all it does is executing HTTP requests and measuring response times. Ideally it should be you, who takes JMeter raw results, performs analysis and creating the final report highlighting current problems and bottlenecks (and ideally what needs to be done to fix them)

Consider the following checklist:

1. You load test needs to be realistic, a test which doesn't represent real-life application usage does not make sense. So make sure your JMeter test carefully represents real users in terms of [cookies](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager), [headers](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager), [cache](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager), downloading images, styles and scripts, virtual user groups distribution, etc.
2. Increase and decrease the load gradually, this way you will be able to correlate such metrics as transactions per second and response time with increasing/decreasing number of users so make sure you apply reasonable [ramp-up and ramp-down settings](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-ramp-steps-your-load-tests).
3. Monitor the application under test health. The reason of error may be as simple as lack of hardware resources (CPU, RAM, Disk, etc.). It can be done using i.e. [PerfMon JMeter Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/).
4. Do the same for JMeter instance(s). JMeter measures response time from "just before sending the request" until "last response byte arrives" so if JMeter is not able to send requests fast enough - you will have high response time without other visible reason.

Answer (score 0):

Website load time is a combination of many factors including the browser rendering time, script execution time, resource download time etc. You can't use JMeter to validate the front end time. You can achieve it using chrome developer tools and other similar tools available for each browser. Refer https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/

JMeter is primarily used for measuring the protocol level performance to ensure that you server can process the heavy workloads when it is subjected to real time stress conditions from several customers. It won't compute the java script execution time or HTML parsing time. Your JMeter script should be written in such a way that it emulates the logic of your java script executions and other presentation logic to form the request inputs and the subsequent requests.

Your question is way too open ended and you might have to start with a mentor who can help you with the whole process and train you.

Also, the mindset for functional testing and performance testing are totally different. Lot of key players in the performance area have suggested to measure the load time as part of the functional testing efforts while the majority of the server side performance is validated by the performance team.